# What is the Proper Setup of Oozie Libpath with respect to HDFS replication?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie

If setting libpath for oozie jobs with the following job properties:

```
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/usernamexxx/share/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
```

(lots of a cluster's oozie jobs use this setting), should the HDFS replication factor be much higher than 3 or even be across all nodes?

Comment: In my case, the main jar is the spark-assembly jar (where some spark under-the-hood magic occurs) and is 221 MB.

Answer (score 0):

That directory isn't very large, and therefore network IO won't be significant, but it also therefore doesn't hurt to try to have a full replica on every datanode.

That property isn't needed for every oozie job, by the way. You  should determine if it is really needed.